# How to implement a transformer into a boost converter instead of an inductor

Tags: transformer, boost, converter

I am trying to build a boost converter that would output a high DC voltage (several hundreds). My concern is that I should use a transformer, but how should I implement it so that DC voltage input is possible? Do I need to use an DC/AC inverter before the transformer?

I've been told that an isolation transformer can take DC voltage..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look into flyback converters.

Comment: You need a special transformer with an air gap.

Comment: @MadHatter Don't flyback converters use coupled inductors, not transformers?

Comment: @Janka Can you specify what you mean by an air gap? Where can I find such transformers?

Comment: @Honeybutter Typically you wind one or buy one, you can get something like an EE core of ferrite. Your right a flyback is a coupled inductor, but they work well for <50W power systems that require >5x boost or reduction of voltage. I recently used a simple flyback design for a 24V to 400V Supply to drive a tube amplifier.

Answer (score -1):

You can look for a forward converter, which is more energy efficient than a flyback converter and fits your needs:

[image]

Comment: I read about this and it seems to work like a buck converter, not a boost converter.

Comment: @Honeybutter Sort of, but you have a turns ratio so you can have an output voltage higher than the input.  But a flyback is the simplest, cheapest option unless you need lots of output power (>~50W)

Comment: @Honeybutter You have to adjust the turns ratio, and thus you can step-up or down your voltage, with much less magnetic cost and fits well if you want to handle more power

Comment: @JohnD Thank you for the reply. Do you know the relevant equation for the output voltage?

Comment: @IronMaiden If I want to go up to 1000V, will that be possible?

Comment: For low power, you can make a few voltage doublers on the output.

Comment: @Honeybutter If you input 10+V and use a 1:100 winding ratio, you'll output at 1000V. Finding diodes and capacitors that can take that voltage costs a bit, and also make sure that your insulation is rated for more than that voltage.

Comment: Forward is a poor solution for high voltages because the transformer, inductor and diode stray capacitances add, making everything much worse.